# inserting into a 3d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, exception, insert

I am getting a type error trying to insert into a 3d array: "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable". I have checked and confirmed that the counters are working correctly (for the z counter, x=-1 is part of a larger loop I have excluded here).  I want to take the string temp and put it at [0][0][0] of the array temp2, iterate my counters and keep adding to the list but I obviously do not know how to do this. Do i need to initialize the array temp2 somehow and how do I do that when I do not know how big it should be? thank for the help.

Initialized at the top of the program:

```
temp2=[]
t=0
temp=""
```

This is the code that raises the exception

```
z=-1
for subtree in result.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.node == 'Proper'):
    z=z+1
    y=0

    # this iterates through the actual subtree
    for p in subtree:
        temp = str(p[0])

        temp2.insert([t][z][y],temp)  #This line raises the exception
        y=y+1

#increments the first dimension of the array and resets the temp list      
t=t+1
temp = ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `defaultdict` like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
temp2 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))

temp2[t][z][y] = temp
```

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
temp2 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))
temp2[1][2][3] = 4
print temp2[1][2][3]
```

**Output**

```
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is collection included as a python library or do I have to install it? it says that I don't have the module.

Comment: @EnglishGrad Sorry. That was a typo. I fixed it now. Its actually `collections`. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  This creates a dictionary of dictionaries right?  This works for what I need, but just for reference is there a way to do this with lists?

Comment: @EnglishGrad This is the best way to do this. If you want to do with lists, you need to dynamically create nested lists and you should know the size of the lists.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest that if you really want a 3D array in Python, either look for a library that already has one (maybe numpy), or write a class that when passed the dimensions in the constructor creates an array with the correct "shape".

Without that, you can accidentally end up with ragged "arrays".